# Spring-boot error: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.8.RELEASE:run

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

After installing Springboot on NetBeans IDE and running the project using the default dependencies of Maven/Spring Initialzr:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

the console logs:

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.8.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project demo: Could not exec java: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

Is there a standard solution for this?

Update: Complete pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: can you post the complete pom.xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not exec java with Spring+Maven exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157515/could-not-exec-java-with-springmaven-exit-code-1)

Comment: The possible duplicate doesn't help at all

Comment: @Santos I just posted it.

Comment: Please add the logging output ...cause your application seemed to be having issues...

Comment: @khmarbaise I just noticed that above: Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.demo.DemoApplication.

Comment: although this class exists

Comment: <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
 can you add this under <properties> in pom.xml and do a maven clean install. and try